# Recuperar valores de um array da linha seguinte na linha anterior

Tags: php, array, foreach, phpexcel

Tenho um array no formato abaixo:

Array
(

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [A] => 000001001000003001
        [B] => VLR REF COMPENSACAO DE VENDA CONFORME CO1
        [C] => 1.1.2.01.020001
        [D] => Z4
        [E] => 
        [F] => 
        [G] => 
        [H] =>           100.000,00
        [I] => 
        [J] =>       4.703.615,60 C
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [A] => 
        [B] => MPRA DE EQUIPAMENTO DO FORNECEDOR PARANA 1
        [C] => 
        [D] => 
        [E] => 
        [F] => 
        [G] => 
        [H] => 
        [I] => 
        [J] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [A] => 
        [B] => EQUIPAMENTOS S.A. - NF VENDA 000000261 1
        [C] => 
        [D] => 
        [E] => 
        [F] => 
        [G] => 
        [H] => 
        [I] => 
        [J] => 
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [A] => 008850001000002098
        [B] => PG. DOC. 3 000113169  TP:NF FORNEC.:0000
        [C] => 
        [D] => Y1
        [E] => 
        [F] => 
        [G] => 
        [H] =>             2.188,35
        [I] => 
        [J] =>           8.901,01 C
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [A] => 
        [B] => 38-PARANA EQUIPAMENTOS S.A.
        [C] => 
        [D] => 
        [E] => 
        [F] => 
        [G] => 
        [H] => 
        [I] => 
        [J] => 
    )
```

)

E preciso que o array fique em outro formato, conforme exemplo abaixo:

Array
(

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [A] => 000001001000003001
        [B] => VLR REF COMPENSACAO DE VENDA CONFORME CO1 MPRA DE EQUIPAMENTO DO FORNECEDOR PARANA 1 EQUIPAMENTOS S.A. - NF VENDA 000000261 1
        [C] => 1.1.2.01.020001
        [D] => Z4
        [E] => 
        [F] => 
        [G] => 
        [H] =>           100.000,00
        [I] => 
        [J] =>       4.703.615,60 C
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [A] => 
        [B] => 
        [C] => 
        [D] => 
        [E] => 
        [F] => 
        [G] => 
        [H] => 
        [I] => 
        [J] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [A] => 
        [B] => 
        [C] => 
        [D] => 
        [E] => 
        [F] => 
        [G] => 
        [H] => 
        [I] => 
        [J] => 
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [A] => 008850001000002098
        [B] => PG. DOC. 3 000113169  TP:NF FORNEC.:0000 38-PARANA EQUIPAMENTOS S.A.
        [C] => 
        [D] => Y1
        [E] => 
        [F] => 
        [G] => 
        [H] =>             2.188,35
        [I] => 
        [J] =>           8.901,01 C
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [A] => 
        [B] => 
        [C] => 
        [D] => 
        [E] => 
        [F] => 
        [G] => 
        [H] => 
        [I] => 
        [J] => 
    )
```

)

Alguma ideia de como eu poderia fazer isto?

Caso eu tenha feito a pergunta de forma errada, essa é a primeira vez que pergunto.

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer fazer. Você quer pear só um dos elementos do array?

Comment: Esse array é montado pelo PHPExcel. A planilha tem mais registros, porém, coloquei somente estes como exemplo. Vou editar a pergunta com mais registro para tentar deixar mais claro o que estou tentando fazer.

Comment: não entendi o que você está tentando fazer também

Comment: O que não entendemos foi sua pergunta, "pegar um valor da linha seguine na linha anterior". Tente deixar sua dúvida mais clara pra podermos entender.

Answer (score 0):

Não basta um laço de repetição?

Considerando que seu array esteja declarado dessa maneira :

```
$arr = [
    [
        'A' => '000001001000003001',
        'B' => 'VLR REF COMPENSACAO DE VENDA CONFORME CO1',
        'C' => '1.1.2.01.020001',
        'D' => 'Z4',
        'E' => '',
        'F' => '',
        'G' => '',
        'H' => '',
        'I' => '100.000,00',
        'J' => '4.703.615,60 C'
    ],[
        'A' => '',
        'B' => 'MPRA DE EQUIPAMENTO DO FORNECEDOR PARANA 1',
        'C' => '',
        'D' => '',
        'E' => '',
        'F' => '',
        'G' => '',
        'H' => '',
        'I' => '',
        'J' => ''
    ],[
        'A' => '',
        'B' => 'EQUIPAMENTOS S.A. - NF VENDA 000000261 1',
        'C' => '',
        'D' => '',
        'E' => '',
        'F' => '',
        'G' => '',
        'H' => '',
        'I' => '',
        'J' => ''
    ]
];
```

Bastaria percorrer os arrays, concatenando os valores com o primeiro item do array, e então passando uma string vazia para o item atual.

```
for ($i = 1; $i < count($arr); ++$i) {
    foreach ($arr[$i] as $chave => $valor) {
        if ($valor !== '') {
            $arr[0][$chave] .= " $valor";
            $arr[$i][$chave] = '';      
        }
    }
}
```